# AT commands in hex format

Tags: command, hex, gsm, at-command

I'm trying to find out the hex format commands equivalent to some common AT arduino commands but i can't find any sources for it,can someone tell me were i can find a documentation that perhaps gathers all AT commands and their equivalent hex formats.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you change it with a hex converter?

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: Something like this: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html
and then write that hex values in your array (guess that you're using C?)

Comment: Ok now i feel dum....Don't know how it didn't cross my mind that the commands where simply ascii characters being transmitted.C++ actually but yeah the same thing.Thanks a lot.